# How to use trove for multi hashmap with byte array as key?

Tags: java, guava, trove4j, bigdata

currently I'm working with an `ArrayListMultiMap` of Guave where I handle over 100.000 items. The key of the map is a `byte array`, the values are `long`.

Now I want to reduce the overhead.

My idea is to use only primitive collections and the hashmap of `trove`. So in the end each key (byte array) points to a primitive collection (primitive long set).

My question is how to use a byte array as key in a THashmap. In Guave I wrapped the byte array in a class, but this produces overhead.

thank you

Comment: You could use something like Chronicle Map to store the byte[] and the long off heap.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `TCustomHashMap` for the outer map because you'll want to come up with a hashing strategy for the `byte[]` (really, just one that calls `Arrays.hashCode(byte[])` would be good).

Within the outer map, use a `TLongHashSet` (or whatever) for values and you're all set.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this solution

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `byte array` as the key directly (no need to wrap it, etc.):

```
Map<byte[], TLongSet> map = new THashMap<>();
map.put(new byte[]{-0x80, 0x7F}, new TLongHashSet(new long[]{0xFFFFFFFF, 0x7FFFFFFF}));
System.out.println(map);
```

Example output:

```
{[B@4d7e1886={2147483647,-1}}
```

EDIT:

If you do not want identity-based keys then you can use `TByteArrayList` instead of `byte[]`. On my machine it has an overhead of 25 bytes per instance. If each of your 100,000 items/longs were stored in its own `TLongSet` each mapped to a unique `byte array` then this makes an overhead of 2.5 megabytes (25 bytes x 100,000). This seems acceptable to me as a worse-case-scenario but if you do want to avoid it then [Rob Eden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1949537/rob-eden)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39147581/3255152) with a `TCustomHashMap` seems the way to go.

Comment: This won't work as-is because you won't be able to search for keys since equals/hashCode won't work for arrays the way you would want them to. (They're identity-based, not value-based.) You'll want to use TCustomHashMap with a HashingStrategy instead.

Comment: @RobEden, good point. The questioner did not specify why they were wrapping the byte array but that is likely why. Thank you for pointing that out.